# Perl DBI: uneven-number of bind variables with OR Statement (called with x bind variables when y are needed)

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd

**Definition of task**:
Fetch data from two different columns using **OR**.

**Problem**:
While its working with the plain (MySQL) query, Perl DBI throws an exception due to the uneven-number of **bind** *variables*.

Let's assume the following DB schema:

```
customer    vpn_primary_ip   vpn_secondary_ip
1000        1.1.1.1          2.2.2.2
1001        3.3.3.3          NULL
1002        4.4.4.4          5.5.5.5
1003        NULL             6.6.6.6
```

**Side note**:
As the column where the ip address is stored is not predictable, I combine the search for the columns *vpn_primary_ip* AND *vpn_secondary_ip* using the **OR** operator. The *plain* SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT
     customer,
     vpn_primary_ip,
     vpn_secondary_ip,
 FROM
     table
 WHERE
     vpn_primary_ip IN ( '1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6' )
 OR  
     vpn_secondary_ip IN ( '1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6' );
```

The query above gives the following (appropriate) result:

```
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
| customer | vpn_primary_ip  | vpn_secondary_ip |
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
|   1000   | 1.1.1.1         | 2.2.2.2          |
|   1002   | 4.4.4.4         | 5.5.5.5          |
|   1003   | NULL            | 6.6.6.6          |
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

The same SQL query with Perl DBI:

```
 my @ip_addresses = ('1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6');

 my $sth = $dbh->prepare (
     "SELECT
       customer,
       vpn_primary_ip,
       vpn_secondary_ip,
     FROM
       table
     WHERE
       vpn_primary_ip IN ( @{[join',', ('?') x @ip_addresses]} )
     OR  
       vpn_secondary_ip IN ( @{[join',', ('?') x @ip_addresses]} )"
    );

 $sth->execute(@ip_addresses);
```

Throws the following exception:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 4 bind variables when 8 are needed at get_vpn_customers line 211, <DATA> line 1.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 4 bind variables when 8 are needed at get_vpn_customers line 211, <DATA> line 1.
```

The only idea to make it work, is to pass @ip_addresses to the *execute* method **twice**:

```
$sth->execute(@ip_addresses, @ip_addresses);
```

**Question**:
Is this the proper approach or is there another, let's say, *best* or *better practice*?

Comment: This is the proper approach. Perl can't know that you are passing the same set of values twice, so it just expects all 8 values to be specified in the parameters of the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $sth->execute(@ip_addresses, @ip_addresses);
> ```

This is the correct approach. All DBI knows is that you have passed it an SQL query containing eight bind points. It, therefore, needs eight matching values passed to the `execute()` method.

There is no way for Perl, DBI or MySQL to know that the bind values are repeated.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports parameters in the form `$1`, `$2`, so you could repeat these in the query and only pass four parameters. Sadly not possible with MySQL.

Comment: You could also write `$sth->execute((@ip_addresses)x2)` (the parentheses are oddly significant here)

Comment: @Grinnz: I was thinking what you really need is a syntax like `WHERE (vpn_primary_ip OR vpn_secondary_ip) IN (LIST)`. But I've never seen anything like that in any version of SQL.

Comment: You could actually do this with the PostgreSQL array overlap operator, which I believe would look something like `WHERE ARRAY[vpn_primary_ip, vpn_secondary_ip] && ?`, passing `\@ip_addresses` as the single parameter. Not sure how well it would be optimized though.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solution is to *massage* SQL query to workable state before `$sth->execute()`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @ip_addresses = ('1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6');

 my $query = "
    SELECT
       customer,
       vpn_primary_ip,
       vpn_secondary_ip,
     FROM
       table
     WHERE
       vpn_primary_ip IN ( @{[join',', ('?') x @ip_addresses]} )
     OR  
       vpn_secondary_ip IN ( @{[join',', ('?') x @ip_addresses]} )
    ";

say $query;

my $ip_addresses;
my $flag = 0;

for (@ip_addresses) {
    $ip_addresses .= ', ' if $flag;
    $ip_addresses .= "'$_'";
    $flag = 1;
}

$query = "
    SELECT
       customer,
       vpn_primary_ip,
       vpn_secondary_ip,
     FROM
       table
     WHERE
       vpn_primary_ip IN ( $ip_addresses )
     OR  
       vpn_secondary_ip IN ( $ip_addresses )
    ";

say $query;
```

Output

```
SELECT
   customer,
   vpn_primary_ip,
   vpn_secondary_ip,
 FROM
   table
 WHERE
   vpn_primary_ip IN ( ?,?,?,? )
 OR
   vpn_secondary_ip IN ( ?,?,?,? )


SELECT
   customer,
   vpn_primary_ip,
   vpn_secondary_ip,
 FROM
   table
 WHERE
   vpn_primary_ip IN ( '1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6' )
 OR
   vpn_secondary_ip IN ( '1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6' )
```